# How to encrypt the string using Bellaso Cipher license in TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript, encryption, palantir-foundry

I need to encrypt Palantir Foundry Workshop application's user data using Bellaso license and send it via the webhook.

We have created a Workshop application which is used by many users. The application sends many REST calls to my customer's webservice via webhooks. My customer requires to add the executor trace to every REST call. The executor trace my customer needs is a base64 encoded JSON string containing current application user's metadata: user ID, first name, last name and position. I.e.`{"id": "encrypted user id", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "position": "Manager"}`. Finally the request should look something like this:

```
{
    "body": {
      "foo": "bar"     
    },
    "executorTrace": "my base64 encoded executor trace goes here" 
}
```

Our administrator has provided Bellaso license, but I have found no way to use it in my TypeScript function.

How can I encrypt the data on the fly using Bellaso encryption license in my TypeScript function?

Comment: We are actively adding support for these features, if you would like to be an early adopter please reach out through your internal support channels. Alternatively, once this feature is in General Availability we’ll come back to answer the question.